# Proof on Limits

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I have been working on the problem below and I am stuck. I am stuck primarily because of the part where is says $x=0$. If $x=0$, it should cancel everything out. The derivative of $0$ is $0$ so will cancel everything out I think, so I am not sure if that is the reasoning and the proof behind it.

> Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is diff. at $x=0$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, $c\ne 0$, then
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{cx}=\frac{a-b}{c}f'(0).$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the quotient as 
$$\frac1c\biggl(\frac{f(ax)-f(a\cdot0)}x-\frac{f(bx)-f(b\cdot0)}x\biggr).$$

Comment: Do you need substitution and the chain-rule? I am curious if my proof is right.

Comment: Yes, it requires the chain rule.

Comment: Technically you don't need the chain rule, since for example $\frac{f(ax)-f(a\cdot 0)}{x}$ can be rewritten as $a\frac{f(ax)-f(a\cdot 0)}{ax}$ if $a\ne 0$ (and if $a=0$ things are simple).

Comment: @André Nicolas: Of course, but everyone knows the chain rule, and substitution is the first  step towards a proof of the chain rule,  so I didn't think useful to use a poorman's chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(0)$ exists we have $$f(ax) = f(0) + axf'(0) + o(x), f(bx) = f(0) + bxf'(0) + o(x)$$ and therefore $$\frac{f(ax) - f(bx)}{cx} = \frac{a - b}{c}\cdot f'(0) + o(1)$$ and letting $x \to 0$ we get the desired result.